# AddListener works but RemoveListener dont work properly

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to remove listener. When i add listener, it works. But when i try to remove it doesn't remove it and listener still works. How can i remove listener properly? Can someone help me?

Here is the function with parameters to add Listener and remove Listener. It also includes the listener function which could be used later.

**Edit1:** If i try to RemoveListener after adding it. It is works. But if i try to use it dynamically with parameters. It doesn't work.

```
// In DoSomething.js
     function Channel(ChannelName,Op)
        {
            //This function will be listened. The reason i am using this inside of another function is to use for ChannelName parameter. I don't want to use that "ChannelName" parameter within (from,message) part. 
            var ChannListener = function ChannFunc(from,message)
            {
                if(typeof message === 'undefined') return;
                ChannelName = ChannelName + "something";
               //snip
            }
        
            Channel.ChannListener = ChannListener;
        
            switch(Op)
            {
                case 1:
                {
                    bot.addListener('msg'+ChannelName.toLowerCase(),ChannListener);
                    break;
                }
        
                case 0:
                {
                    bot.removeListener('msg'+ChannelName.toLowerCase(),ChannListener);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

It is adding listener function. After loop, depending on the value of JSON, listeners are adding via Channel function.

```
// In DoSomething.js
    var GetFromJsonFunction = function()
    {
        const Data = fs.readFileSync('/path/to/something.json', {encoding:'utf8'});
        var TempData = JSON.parse(Data);
        for(var i=0;i<TempData.Block.length;i++)
        {
            Channel(TempData.Block[i]._textValue,1);
        }
    }
    GetFromJsonFunction();
```

In here, i want to remove that listener. So i used the same function with 0/1 parameter. 0 is executing RemoveListener, 1 is executing AddListener command in the Channel function.

```
// In DoSomething.js
       /*
        * @param1 Channel Name - String
        * @param2 Callback - String
        */
        exports.DeleteChann = function(IncomingMessage, CallBack)
        {
            //snip
           Channel(IncomingMessage,0);
           CallBack("success");
            //snip
        }
```

This one is to used for DeleteChann function from another file.

```
// In index.js
        OtherFile.DeleteChann(SendMessage, function(CallBack) 
        {
            //snip
           console.log(CallBack);
            //snip
        });
```

Comment: Which library are you using that contains "addListener"?

Comment: @James https://github.com/martynsmith/node-irc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So pub-sub paradigm or these kind of eventemitter work:

1. When a function is added as listener it adds it to an array.
2. When it is removed it checks for the function and removes it.

In your case everytime `Channel(..)` is called, a new `ChannListener` is created. So when you try to remove it as the memory location(pointer) is different it never finds the function that it needs to remove.

So, you need to shift `ChannListener` outside so that only 1 function is created. Remember, only the SAME function can be removed.

**EDIT**:

As you said you need it inside, you can create a Map outside of the function that holds the function.

like,

```js
var ChannListener = function ChannFunc(from,message)
{
  if(typeof message === 'undefined') return;
  ChannelName = ChannelName + "something";
  
}
channelMap["some_uniq_thing"] = ChannListener;

# and after that remove it:

bot.removeListener(..., channelMap["some_uniq_thing]);
```

**EDIT**
A primitive example would be (you probably need to find the edge cases):

```
/// In DoSomething.js
const listenerMap = {};
function Channel(ChannelName, Op) {
  //This function will be listened. The reason i am using this inside of another function is to use for ChannelName parameter. I don't want to use that "ChannelName" parameter within (from,message) part. 
  var ChannListener = function ChannFunc(from, message) {
    if (typeof message === 'undefined') return;
    ChannelName = ChannelName + "something";
    //snip
  }

  Channel.ChannListener = ChannListener;
  if(!listenerMap[ChannelName]) // don't overwrite functions.
    listenerMap[ChannelName] = ChannListener;
  switch (Op) {
    case 1:
      {
        bot.addListener('msg' + ChannelName.toLowerCase(), listenerMap[ChannelName]);
        break;
      }

    case 0:
      {
        bot.removeListener('msg' + ChannelName.toLowerCase(), listenerMap[ChannelName]);
        break;
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: How can i pass ChannelName parameter without using in the ChannListener ChannFunc(from,message)? I don't want to add ChannelParameter in the (from,message) part.

Comment: yeah so as I said you can store it somewhere and remove that.

Comment: That's a great idea but i am not following. Can you write the whole Map code thing? I used maps before but i don't properly understand how to use it when exporting that ChannListener for use in another function.

Comment: I moved that function to outside. Is there any way to addListener() with parameters? For example i want to add listener to ChannListener function. But i also want to pass ChannelName parameter to it with using addListener(param) function. If it's possible how can i use it that way? Because when i moved that function to outside, code can't see the ChannelName = ChannelName + "something" part. Because ChannelName does not part of the function.

Comment: It now works! Thank you for the help. Can you explain the map part?

Comment: yeah i am basically storing the pointer outside the scope of the function(think like global-ish), so that i can use the same function pointer

Comment: What happens if i add listener outside of this function on another file with different variables like AddListener(msg+ChannelName.toLowerCase(),somefunct). If i remove the first listener as you made in example, will it remove the second listener? I mean will all listeners remove?

Comment: As long as the pointer is same it will remove that function. if it is different it won't. simple as that.